# How to add a third-party Action Helper to a Zend Framework 1.8+ application?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

I have downloaded a third party action helper that I would like to add to my application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Noginn SendFile Action Helper](http://www.noginn.com/2009/03/08/sending-files-with-the-zend-framework/) as a reference, dropped into the library directory, the directory structure looks like this:

```
/library
    /Noginn
        /Controller
            /Action
                /Helper
                    /SendFile.php
```

In `/application/Bootstrap.php` add an init function and add the class prefix:

```
protected function _initActionHelpers()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Noginn_Controller_Action_Helper');
}
```

Then in your controller, you can call the action helper like this:

```
$this->_helper->sendFile($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [The Helper Broker](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.broker)

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Your_Controller_Action_Helper());
```

Just make sure that `Your_Controller_Action_Helper` is auto-loadable, or is included.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add it in straight forward manner:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Wow_Controller_Action_Helper_Auth());
```

You can also add to helper broker prefix, as Andrew did, or add path to your new helpers. All these options are well explained [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.broker).