# Sending multipart response for downloads in Zend Framework

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, download, response

I'm sending files in action helper for downloads (in parts if needed) like this:

```
...
$response->sendHeaders();

$chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024);
$bytesSent = 0;

if ($httpRange) {
    fseek($file, $range);
}

while(!feof($file) &&
   (!connection_aborted() &&
   ($bytesSent < $newLength))
) {
    $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
//      $response->appendBody($buffer); // this would be better
    print($buffer);
    flush();
    $bytesSent += strlen($buffer);
}
fclose($file);
```

I suspect that better way would be to make use of `$response` object instead of `print`.

Which is the recommended way to send big response objects using Zend Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I use Noginn Action Helper to send file for downloads.
Here is a good description in another answer:
[How to add a third-party Action Helper to a Zend Framework 1.8+ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910391/how-to-add-a-third-party-action-helper-to-a-zend-framework-1-8-application/1910500#1910500)

Url to SendFile.php:
https://github.com/noginn/noginn/blob/master/Noginn/Controller/Action/Helper/SendFile.php